# Why in IntentService super.OnCreate delete a notification startForeground()

Tags: android, foreground-service

I'm continuing in the Android studies and i've a questions.

I'have this intentService:

```
public class SystemService extends IntentService{
    public SystemService() {
       super("SystemService");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
       return(START_NOT_STICKY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        startForeground();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void startForeground(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle("Foregroundservice")
            .setContentText("foreground is active")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    startForeground(1337, noti);
    }
}
```

Why, in onCreate() function,  if I put the function startForeground() so, ne initializing foregroundservice before the super.onCreate(), the foreground notify disappear But if a put after seem work?

Comment: Because `super.onCreate()` does stuff that conflicts with your intentions

Comment: Have a look at the super class (`IntentService`) to see what happens ..